# Django form field display name

Tags: django, forms, models

I m trying to make a form on the basis of a model. Trouble is that when i create a `category` via `django shell`, let's say "Wedding" category, having `id=1` and `name = "weddings"`, when i display it in a dropdown(in html form) it shows as `Categories object (1)` and i would like it to be shown by the name, which is `weddings`.

As in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) i understand that i can attach `labels` when in the `Meta` form class but i don't fully understand how i can display dynamically all the category names instead of Categories object 1,2,3,4.

> Models.py

```
class categories(model.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key =True)
    name = models.Charfield(max_length = 50)

class Event(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key =True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null = True)
    owner = models.Charfield(max_length = 50)
```

> Forms.py

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Event
    fields = ['category','person','owner']
```

So the actual result when rendering the form is :

```
Category:(dropdown) - Categories object (1)
```

Desired result:

```
Category:(dropdown) - weddings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class categories(model.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key =True)
    name = models.Charfield(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Event(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key =True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null = True)
    owner = models.Charfield(max_length = 50)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.owner
```

just add this little magic functions to your model classes.

Comment: this did it, i'm going to accept it but i have to wait 10 mins. Is there somewhere where i can read a detailed `why` so i can understand better? Nevertheless, thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: i've read in general about the __str__ function but i didn't make the connection here right away:0